# ckeditor error code editor-destroy-iframe in angularjs

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

This error is reported after I have called the destroy method of ckeditor,[this is Official documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_errors-section-editor-destroy-iframe)
anybody help me?

Comment: `if (CKEDITOR.instances["content"]) {
                CKEDITOR.instances["content"].destroy();
  }`

Comment: this is destory method